# Passing argument from Main method

Tags: java, dictionary

Here is my complete code. My challenge is in the last 3 lines! I can't send the argument (int r) to findColor(int r). Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks

```
import java.util.*;
public class NewClass {
private HashMap <Character,HashSet> colorMap ;

public NewClass() {
    colorMap = new HashMap<Character, HashSet>();
}

public void addColor(){
    HashSet a1 = new HashSet();
    a1.add("Yellow");
    a1.add("Blue");
    a1.add("Pink");
    colorMap.put('X', a1);
    HashSet a2 = new HashSet();
    a2.add("White");
    a2.add("Brown");
    a2.add("Blue");
    a2.add("Black");
    colorMap.put('W', a2);
}    

public Set<String> findColor(int r)
{
Set<String> colors = new HashSet<String>();
    {
    for(Character m : colorMap.keySet())

    if(r < colorMap.size())
        {
        Set<String> zone = colorMap.get(m);
        System.out.println("Zone " + zone + " has more than " + r + " colors");
        }        
    }
    return colors;
 }    

 public static void main(String [] args){

    Set<String> colors;
    NewClass a = new NewClass();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a numbers \n");
    int r = input.nextInt();
    colors = findColor(r);
    a.findColor(r);      
}    
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you? Are you getting an error message? Does it not compile? You need to be more specific abou what the actual problem is or your question might get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 1):

One issue I could tell is:

```
    int r = input.nextInt();
    //colors = findColor(r);
    Set<String> colors = a.findColor(r);
```

Remove second line

`findColor(int r`) is not a static method, so you can't directly call inside a static method, you need to use instance reference (Which is line3 in above code).

Comment: What is the contents of colors at the end?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is read from the command line. Do this:

http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010005

The second of the last 3 lines is wrong. Add the a. before the method call, and delete the 3rd line.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your last 3 lines:

```
int r = input.nextInt();
colors = findColor(r);
a.findColor(r);
```

On line 2, you are trying to call `findColor` from a static method, but `findColor` is not static. That is not allowed; non-static methods must be called through an instance of the particular class the non-static method belongs to.

You do actually have an instance of `NewClass` in the scope of your `main` function, which you have called `a`. So, simply call `findColor` through that instance:

```
int r = input.nextInt();
colors = a.findColor(r);
```

Comment: Thank you! Well noted. However, it's not working as expected!